# PL/SQL trigger to modify newly inserted data

Tags: plsql, triggers, insertion

*All the commands below are executed apart from each other r in the order i wrote them:*

So here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE clase (
clasa VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY,
tip VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL,
tara varchar(30) NOT NULL,
nr_arme NUMBER(3, 0) NOT NULL,
diametru_tun NUMBER(3,0) NOT NULL,
deplasament NUMBER(6, 0) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT chk_diam_tun CHECK ((diametru_tun > 15 AND nr_arme < 10) OR diametru_tun <= 15)
);
```

the creation doesn't have any mistakes and works perfectly. The next step is to create a trigger that checks on insertion if the value of **deplasament** is **lower than 10000** and changes it automatically to 10000.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t_clase_insert
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON clase
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF(:NEW.deplasament < 10000) THEN
   :NEW.deplasament := 10000;
END IF;
END;
```

It compiles the trigger with no error. Next i test the trigger with the code:

```
INSERT INTO clase
(clasa, tip, tara, nr_arme, diametru_tun, deplasament)
VALUES
('My_class', 'mc', 'Europe', 10, 3, 8000);
```

And the output is:

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'DATABASEFORSCHOOL.CLASA_ADAUGARE' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

I tried to see if it's an syntax error with:

```
select * 
from 
user_errors 
where 
type = 'TRIGGER' 
and 
name = 't_clase_insert';
```

but no data found. Does anyone comprehend why the trigger doesn't work and why i can't insert data?

Comment: It works, check this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=304b23b6bd2cb458981c13375207a562)

Comment: Haha, funny :)) That means that APEX cannot execute this code, i don't know why... :))

Comment: What das this select return? Select * from all_triggers where table_name = 'CLASE'; I pretend you have another trigger on this table.

Comment: @MichalSv now i can see that i have another trigger that i created trying to do the same task, I probably should drop it. I will try and than tell you if it works. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it worked. Now i can insert values and the trigger performs correctly. Thank you once again